# Attempts to log py.test setup, call, and teardown duration results in unexpected order of log output

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I'm using Python 3.4.3 and pytest-2.7.2.  Following the docs, I wrote this in my conftest.py:

```
import logging
import time

import pytest


logging.basicConfig(
    level='INFO',
    handlers=(
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
    )
)

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    logging.info('%s TEARDOWN >>>', item.nodeid)
    start = time.time()
    outcome = yield
    end = time.time()
    logging.info('%s TEARDOWN <<< %fs', item.nodeid, end - start)
```

And a trivial test.py:

```
def test_something():
    pass
```

Using py.test test.py -vvv, exhibits the problem.  Note that the log message, that I would have expected py.test to hide, escapes and is printed later (after the summary line).

```
======= test session starts ======
...snip...

test.py::test_something PASSED


==== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ====
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN <<< 0.000368s
```

Adding -s to avoid capture, displays everything as expected:

```
======= test session starts ======
...snip...

test.py::test_something PASSEDINFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN >>>
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN <<< 0.000207s


==== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ====
```

Now, this example is simplified a bit.  In my actual conftest.py, I'm outputing the same kind of logging for pytest_runtest_setup() and pytest_runtest_call() as well.

log.txt looks fine for both invocations:

```
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN >>>
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN <<< 0.000207s
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN >>>
INFO:root:test.py::test_something TEARDOWN <<< 0.000326s
```

I even have a pytest_unconfigure() implemented that prints (using print) some links at the end of the run.  The message that manages to escape (only without specifying -s) even displays after that content!

Using py.test --debug, you can see that the scope of pytest_runtest_teardown() should not include pytest_unconfigure():

```
...snip...
        pytest_runtest_teardown [hook]
            item: <Function 'test_something'>
            nextitem: None
        finish pytest_runtest_teardown --> [] [hook]
...snip...
      finish pytest_runtest_protocol --> True [hook]
    finish pytest_runtestloop --> True [hook]
    pytest_sessionfinish [hook]
...snip...
    finish pytest_sessionfinish --> [] [hook]
    pytest_unconfigure [hook]
        config: <_pytest.config.Config object at 0x7f8a46be6a90>
    finish [config:tmpdir]
```

I'm not sure if this is a py.test bug (in hookwrapper or the output capturing, perhaps?) or some kind of logging buffering biting me...  Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that when multiple tests are run, only the last teardown has this problem.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that just using print instead of logging works as expected too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try the following code

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(call: CallInfo):
    logger.info(f"⏱ {call.when} time: {call.duration}")
```